# AnnotationProcessor option not recorgnized by any processor

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I have written an annotation processor. The user can pass an option as parameter for the processor. I can also read this parameter in my annotation processor. So far so good, everything works like expected!

However, I get a warning from the compiler, that the option passed to the annotation processor has not been recorgnized by any annotation processor:

> Warning:The following options were not recognized by any processor:
>   '[fragmentArgsLib]'

Actually, my processor has recognized and read this option successfully:

```
@Override public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> type, RoundEnvironment env) {

    String fragementArgsLib = processingEnv.getOptions().get("fragmentArgsLib");
    ... 
}
```

I guess I have to say manually that I have used this option to make this compiler warning disappear. Does anyone of you know how to do that?

Comment: Might be just a typo in your post, but your code fragment declares a variable with name `fragementArgsLib` instead of `fragmentArgsLib`

Comment: yes, thats a typo, but that's just a variable name ... the `getOptions.get("fragmentArgsLib")` is correct and is matching `'[fragmentArgsLib]'` ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer, you have to specify which options are supported by your annotation processor by overriding  `getSupportedOptions()` or using `@SupportedOptions` annotation (since java 7)